# Wordpress Plugin Functionality on Static Site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, static

Is there some way to implement the functionality of a Wordpress plugin on a static site?

For example, if I have a static html site at http://mystaticsiteatroot.com
and have a Wordpress installation in a subdirectory such as http://mystaticsiteatroot.com/wordpblog,
could I then somehow call one of the functions or returns of a Wordpress plugin by placing Javascript on http://mystaticsiteatroot.com, or one of its static subpages such as http://mystaticsiteatroot.com/static-page-2/?

One example of this would be implementing a Javascript popup form on the static homepage which is generated by a premium Wordpress plugin.

I know it would be on a plugin by plugin basis, but I want to get a general understanding of how it might work.

Comment: you can use iframe or ajax call from your static page

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) if you wish to *move a Root install to its own directory*, OR wish to *use a pre-existing subdirectory install* Or wish to *point your home site's URL to a subdirectory*

If you wish to generate static HTML pages for your site/blog, you can [check this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-static/)

If you wish to automatically wrap a WordPress Theme around static HTML pages, pdf files, audio or video files. [Check this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-pages/)

IF you wish to produce a static HTML version of your WordPress install and adjusts URL accordingly. [Check this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/)